# Why do people think binocular vision is advantageous in sports?

Tags: evolution, philosophy-of-biology

Why do people think binocular vision (visual depth perception) is advantageous in sports? Yes, it can be helpful, but what if binocular vision is an evolutionary dead end? Aren't there plenty of animals with NO binocular vision at all that are apex predators and get around just fine? What if the evolution of binocular vision is a temporary path that only leads to a dead end in the grand scheme of evolution?

Depth perception can also come in the form of sonar and hearing.

So in short, what if the most athletic animals have no visual depth perception at all, and therefore binocular vision should not be considered a proxy for how good you are at sports?

Isn't binocular vision a recent evolutionary trait? Why deny established billion years of evolution and say life was in the dark all that time?

I have another theory for thinking this, but that would take up too much space here.

Comment: [Binocular vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_vision) has advantages. Fullstop

Comment: I said it can be helpful, but that it shouldn't be a deciding factor to how good you are at sports.

Comment: A relative advantage remains just that, and in higher tier competitive sports,  a relative advantage (ceteris paribus) is the difference between winning and losing. If there is something where you have a disadvantage, you have to make up for it. And there is only so much you can make up for without significantly losing performance. Full stop. Sports are a highly competitive field without much forgiveness for any disadvantages.

Comment: Not really, if you give up something for acquiring binocular vision, that means it could be an evolutionary dead end. A relative advantage can be temporary.

Comment: Evolution happens across (hundreds of) thousands of years. Even if some day evolution gets rid of binocular vision in primates (which I doubt), who knows whether humans or their sports still exist? You are blending things here which exist on very different layers of existence and in very different timeframes.

Comment: True, I am just saying to consider the possibility that binocular vision has nothing to do with the best sports performances because binocular vision could hit a plateau. I'm not saying it's true. I'm just saying it might be a possibility because some people think it's not. Yea I know it's stretching, but I have a good reason for it (my other theory that would take too much space here).

Answer (score 2):

the reason animals evolved with multiple eyes is that it confers depth perception, which allows the positions of objects to be accurately represented in the brain in all three dimensions.

Sports activities involving tracking the motion of another person or a ball *require* binocular vision. Try playing left field with one eye taped over and you will understand why.

There are no apex predators with monocular vision, so that premise is false, as is any reasoning based on it. No one I know of who is versed in the field of physiological optics and vision science thinks that binocular vision is an evolutionary dead end, so any reasoning based on that false premise is invalid as well.